# PHP in Javascript, in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I have one PHP file, and have few lines of Javascript in it. But is it possible to put PHP code in the said Javascript code?

```
$addNewSubject = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        function test(id, strTemp) {
                            var SubjectNum = id;
                            SubjectNum++;
                            // php code here
                        }
                    </script>";
```

What I'm trying to do is to put this code in Javascript:

```
$strTableExam = "<TR><TD><input size=10 maxlength=10 type=text name='ExamNewSubject[SubjectNum]'></TD><TD><input size=5 maxlength=5 type=text name='ExamSubjectGrade[SubjectNum]'>strTemp</TD></TR>";
```

If not possible, which/what way should I go?

Comment: using `AJAX` you can do

Comment: any example of using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

using `?><?php` and `echo` the `php variable`

```
<?php
$strTableExam = "<TR><TD><input size=10 maxlength=10 type=text name='ExamNewSubject[SubjectNum]'></TD><TD><input size=5 maxlength=5 type=text name='ExamSubjectGrade[SubjectNum]'>strTemp</TD></TR>";
$addNewSubject = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                           function test(id, strTemp) {
                           var SubjectNum = id;
                           SubjectNum++;
                                "?><?php echo $strTableExam;?><?php echo " }
                   </script>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code by assigning php variable to javascript variable

```
$strTableExam = "<TR><TD><input size=10 maxlength=10 type=text name='ExamNewSubject[SubjectNum]'></TD><TD><input size=5 maxlength=5 type=text name='ExamSubjectGrade[SubjectNum]'>strTemp</TD></TR>";

<script type="text/javascript">
var tableExam = <? echo $strTableExam ?>
</script>
```